# CALCULATE QUARTILES WITH FILTERS - POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to put together a DAX statement in Power BI to calculate the quartiles of a table according to some filters. I did a generic sentence however, I have problems to be able to assign the filters to it.
The table structure is:

| Campaing | management | group | id_oper | name_oper | nom_sup | tickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| convergente | bo tecnico | convergente | 0000000 | operador1 | supervisor1 | 500 |
| convergente | bo tecnico | convergente | 11111111 | operador2 | supervisor1 | 200 |
| convergente | bo tecnico | convergente | 22222222 | operador3 | supervisor1 | 80 |
| convergente | bo tecnico | convergente | 33333333 | operador4 | supervisor1 | 300 |
| despacho | bo despacho | averias | 44444444 | operador5 | supervisor2 | 1500 |
| despacho | bo despacho | averias | 55555555 | operador6 | supervisor2 | 500 |
| despacho | bo despacho | averias | 66666666 | operador7 | supervisor2 | 30 |
| despacho | bo despacho | averias | 77777777 | operador8 | supervisor2 | 1000 |
| multiskill | bo provision | multiskill | 88888888 | operador9 | supervisor3 | 20 |
| multiskill | bo provision | multiskill | 99999999 | operador10 | supervisor3 | 5 |
| multiskill | bo provision | multiskill | 12345678 | operador11 | supervisor3 | 80 |
| multiskill | bo provision | multiskill | 87654321 | operador12 | supervisor3 | 3 |

And the Power BI query that i'm using is this:

```
Quantile = 
IF(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]<= PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.25),"Q4",
IF(AND(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]> PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.25),TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]<= PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.5)),"Q3",
IF(AND(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]> PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.5),TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]<= PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.75)),"Q2",
IF(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets]> PERCENTILE.EXC(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets],0.75),"Q1"))))
```

The query calculates the quartile by operator and it works without problems, but it calculates them on the total of records, and I would like to know how I can calculate the same but with data filters, for example filters of the campaign column.

I would appreciate your help with this problem, and I hope I have explained ... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use New measure:

```
Quantile=
var cur_val = max(TBL_CUARTIL[tickets])  
return IF(cur_val< PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.25),"Q4",
IF(AND(cur_val> PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.25),cur_val<= PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.5)),"Q3",
IF(AND(cur_val> PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.5),cur_val<= PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.75)),"Q2",
IF(cur_val> PERCENTILEX.EXC(ALLSELECTED(TBL_CUARTIL), TBL_CUARTIL[tickets], 0.75),"Q1"))))
```